# writing embedded list in files

Tags: python, list, file

I have python code which is producing following output,

```
[

['3', 'cs2313', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'], 
['5', 'ec3325', 'someone', 'ec301', 'Maths2', 'ec302', 'Theory of Circuits', 'ec303', 'PCB design'], 
['7', 'cs4890', 'someone', 'cs401', 'Game Theory', 'cs402', 'Systems Programming', 'cs403', 'Automata'],
['1', 'ec1008', 'someone', 'ec101', 'Digitization', 'ec102', 'Analog cicuit design', 'ec103', 'IP Telephony'], 
['3', 'cs2002', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'], 
['3', 'cs2009', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming']

]
```

I am writing this in file

```
fo=open("result.txt","w")
print ("Name of file: ",fo.name)
for item in x :
    fo.write("%s\n"% item)
fo.close()
```

The list goes as above mentioned.
But what I want the output in file is

```
 [

    '3', 'cs2313', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming', 
    '5', 'ec3325', 'someone', 'ec301', 'Maths2', 'ec302', 'Theory of Circuits', 'ec303', 'PCB design', 
    '7', 'cs4890', 'someone', 'cs401', 'Game Theory', 'cs402', 'Systems Programming', 'cs403', 'Automata',
    '1', 'ec1008', 'someone', 'ec101', 'Digitization', 'ec102', 'Analog cicuit design', 'ec103', 'IP Telephony', 
    '3', 'cs2002', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming', 
    '3', 'cs2009', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'

    ]
```

meaning each output line separated by a new line.Is there a function call for the same or a better way than what I have written do get the result.

Comment: you mean you want to include `[` and `]` in the output file ?

Comment: That's an odd hybrid between tabular data and nested lists.  If you have nested lists why not leave them as nested lists?  What's wrong with the extra brackets?  One level of listness with brackets and another with newlines?  I say keep it all lists and perhaps write it out with json.  Or jettison lists altogether and go tabular and write a csv file where the structure is denoted with delimiters and newlines.

Comment: If a program is going to read the data that you are writing to the file, then you can use json to dump/read structured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation using `str.join()`:

```
my_list = [

['3', 'cs2313', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'], 
['5', 'ec3325', 'someone', 'ec301', 'Maths2', 'ec302', 'Theory of Circuits', 'ec303', 'PCB design'], 
['7', 'cs4890', 'someone', 'cs401', 'Game Theory', 'cs402', 'Systems Programming', 'cs403', 'Automata'],
['1', 'ec1008', 'someone', 'ec101', 'Digitization', 'ec102', 'Analog cicuit design', 'ec103', 'IP Telephony'], 
['3', 'cs2002', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'], 
['3', 'cs2009', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming']

]

with open('output_file', 'a+') as f_data:
    f_data.write('[\n')
    for elm in my_list:
        # Maybe you don't need to check if the elm is a list ?
        if isinstance(elm, list):
            f_data.write(', '.join("'{}'".format(k) for k in elm) + '\n')
    f_data.write(']\n')
```

Output:

```
$> cat output_file

[
'3', 'cs2313', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'
'5', 'ec3325', 'someone', 'ec301', 'Maths2', 'ec302', 'Theory of Circuits', 'ec303', 'PCB design'
'7', 'cs4890', 'someone', 'cs401', 'Game Theory', 'cs402', 'Systems Programming', 'cs403', 'Automata'
'1', 'ec1008', 'someone', 'ec101', 'Digitization', 'ec102', 'Analog cicuit design', 'ec103', 'IP Telephony'
'3', 'cs2002', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'
'3', 'cs2009', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bad idea, because you're just going to be back here next week asking, "So I have this file in this weird format, but I can't figure out how to parse it…" As Steven Rumbalski suggests in a comment, what you almost certainly want to do is either write it as one big JSON text, or write it as a CSV file. Either of those is trivial to write, just as trivial to parse, and also human-readable and -editable.

But if you really want this format, you just need to work out exactly how to describe it, and then it should be easy to turn into code.

None of it is going to be quite as simple as `json.dump(x, fo)` or `csv.writer(fo).writerows(x)`, but that's because widely useful formats have nice libraries to make them easy to write, and idiosyncratic formats do not.

But it's not going to be *that* hard.

For example, my first guess at your rule is that what you want is exactly the repr of the list, but without the brackets around it:

```
fo.write(str(item).strip('[]') + "\n")
```

Of course this very similar rule also gives the same output for your example, but it's different if you might have triply-nested lists:

```
fo.write(str(item)[1:-1] + "\n")
```

And this rule is also very similar but subtly different:

```
fo.write(', '.join(map(repr, item)) + "\n")
```

Which one do you want? I don't know, but presumably you do.

---

And of course you've also asked for `[` before any of the lines and `]` after all of them, so you have to add that explicitly as well:

```
fo.write('[\n')
for item in x :
    # whichever rule you wanted from above
fo.write(']\n')
```

---

From your edit, it seems like you want some unusual indentation and blank lines, so you have to do that explicitly as well:

```
fo.write(' [\n\n')
for item in x:
    # whichever rule you wanted from above
    # but with a '    ' prefixed to the string
fo.write('\n .   ]\n')
```

Plus, some of your lines now end with a final `,` but others do not. I'm not sure what the rule is for that, but again, if you can explain it, I'm sure you can code it.

Answer (score 1):

You want the string representation of each list minus the brackets joined by comma+linefeed, all wrapped in brackets.

One line does it (`result` being your list of lists):

```
print("[\n{}\n]".format(",\n".join([str(x).strip('[]') for x in result])))
```

prints:

```
[
'3', 'cs2313', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming',
'5', 'ec3325', 'someone', 'ec301', 'Maths2', 'ec302', 'Theory of Circuits', 'ec303', 'PCB design',
'7', 'cs4890', 'someone', 'cs401', 'Game Theory', 'cs402', 'Systems Programming', 'cs403', 'Automata',
'1', 'ec1008', 'someone', 'ec101', 'Digitization', 'ec102', 'Analog cicuit design', 'ec103', 'IP Telephony',
'3', 'cs2002', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming',
'3', 'cs2009', 'someone', 'cs231', 'IT networks', 'cs232', 'IT Workshop', 'cs233', 'IT programming'
]
```

The key parts are:

- `str(x).strip('[]')` which creates/preserves the representation of each list, minus the brackets
- `",\n".join` which joins all lists with comma+linefeed
- `"[\n{}\n]".format` that wraps the joined result into brackets+linefeeds
  (to write into a file, obviously replace `print` by `f.write`, `f` being a file handle)

This solution doesn't support "indentation" for each line, but it's pretty easy if you change `",\n".join` by `",\n   ".join` and make up for the first element:

```
print("[\n   {}\n]".format(",\n   ".join(str(x).strip('[]') for x in result)))
```